# Matching user input with file data

Tags: python-3.x

first of all, I'm new to this site. Hello :)

I have a problem with a program I'm trying to make. What I'm trying to do right now is a login system - so users can enter a username and password (that they've already registered with) and then match the username and password with one in a file called 'accounts.txt'.

This means I can associate data they later generate with their account.

Here's what I have so far:

```
while loop == (2):
 print("Welcome to login.")
 verifyuser = input("Enter your username: ")
 verifypass = input("Enter your password: ")
 f = open("accounts.txt","r")
 for line in f:
  if re.match(verifyuser, line) and match(verifypass, line):
   loop = (3)
```

Loop 3 takes it along to the rest of the program once it's verified. I know this re.match thing doesn't exactly work, but I have no idea how I could go about this, and I've tried several different routes - I don't mean to ask people to do my work for me or anything, I just can't do this specific area.

Thanks

Comment: `if verifyuser in line:` will check if `line` contains username, `if line == verifyuser:` will check if line and username match completely.

Answer (score 0):

re.match is for regular expressions, which don't seem to be used here.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

While I don't recommend user credentials in files, why aren't you using the equals operator?

```
if verifyuser == line:
```

Also, I'm not sure how both verifyuser AND verifypass could be true for the same line?

```
user_match = False
pswd_match = False
for line in f:
    if verifyuser == line:
        user_match = True
    if verifypass == line:
        pswd_match = True
    if user_match and pswd_match:
        # loop = (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done something just like this, I did it in a different way than you. This is what my text file looked like storing the information:

```
 username : password
```

Then I would ask for the information like this:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
username = input('Enter your username: ')
password = input('Enter your password: ')
user = username + ' : ' + password
if user in f.read():
    print('Loggin successful')
else:
    print('incorrect username or password')
```

if you want to give the user like 5 chances you can just add in a nice little for loop.

```
for i in range(5):
    f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
    username = input('Enter your username: ')
    password = input('Enter your password: ')
    user = username + ' : ' + password
    if user in f.read():
        print('Loggin successful')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect username or password')
```

This isn't the same as my script, mines a bit longer, but this should get the job done!

Comment: Do you mind marking it correct? it'd mean a lot and helps, thanks.